# C debugger in Webpage?

Tags: javascript, c++, html

I want build a simple webpage so I can write a C++ code in html page and run the code, then the result showing in the same page.

Is it possible to do this?
If so is there any idea how can I get started?

Comment: You mean something like [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/)?

Comment: So you want to let internet users run arbitrary c code on your server? Have you considered the security implications in a scheme like that?

Comment: Yes, just like ideone.com but simple for one language.

Comment: When you do this, please share the link :)

Answer (score -2):

It is not possible to execute C++ code directly in a browser. It is possible to compile and generate the HTML for a website with C++, though. Visual Studio will help you setup a website built on C++.

Comment: Wrong.  C++ in browser, sent to server, compiled, output captured and sent back to browser.

Comment: [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) - "Emscripten is an LLVM to JavaScript compiler. It takes LLVM bitcode (which can be generated from C/C++ using Clang, or any other language that can be converted into LLVM bitcode) and compiles that into JavaScript, which can be run on the web (or anywhere else JavaScript can run)."

Comment: Sending code to the server where it's executed the results are sent back is not running C++ code *directly* in the browser. Emscripten is interesting. I'll definitely look into that.

Comment: I have heard about exec() function in php will this function run the code and get the result?

Comment: [NativeClient](https://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) allows you to build web applications that seamlessly execute native compiled code inside the browser.

Comment: Since neither Emscripten nor Clang are written in JavaScript, you would still need to send the C++ to the server where it would be converted to JavaScript. The JavaScript could then be returned and executed, but all you've done is found a fancy way to write the JavaScript you are executing in the browser. You still can't run C++ directly in a browser.